# cakephp Form helper, radio does not work as expected

Tags: forms, cakephp, helper

suddenly my radio elements stopped working, I back to the CakePHP official documentation to double-check the implementation of the radio buttons, and I cannot find what I did wrong.
This is my code (I just copied and paste it from the CakePHP docu).

```
echo $this->Form->radio('gender', ['Masculine', 'Feminine', 'Neuter']);
```

And this is how it is rendered in the DOM. For some reason, the labels are missing.
Any clue?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks! Also, when checking for problems in generated HTML, make sure to check the browser's page source view functionality too, not just the DOM inspector, as the latter will a) filter out invalid HTML, and b) show the DOM with possible JavaScript modifications applied!